# Execution of Postgres SQL Select statement slows down by factor 10 after 8 attempts

Tags: java, postgresql

we have a 15000000 entry database and executing a SELECT like

```
SELECT technical_id, attribute_a, attribute_b, attribute_c from test WHERE ( attribute_a_fltr @> (?::character varying[]) OR attribute_a_fltr = '{n/a}') AND ( attribute_b_fltr @> (?::character varying[]) OR attribute_b_fltr = '{n/a}') AND ( attribute_c = ? OR attribute_c = 0)
```

will slow down dramatically after 9 tries. Here are the results

```
Iteration: 0 Entries: 593 time :6931
Iteration: 1 Entries: 593 time :7879
Iteration: 2 Entries: 593 time :8721
Iteration: 3 Entries: 593 time :9490
Iteration: 4 Entries: 593 time :10240
Iteration: 5 Entries: 593 time :11016
Iteration: 6 Entries: 593 time :11736
Iteration: 7 Entries: 593 time :12461
Iteration: 8 Entries: 593 time :13168
Iteration: 9 Entries: 593 time :152329
Iteration: 10 Entries: 593 time :290717
Iteration: 11 Entries: 593 time :435933
Iteration: 12 Entries: 593 time :567401
Iteration: 13 Entries: 593 time :695307
Iteration: 14 Entries: 593 time :835853
```

Here comes the Java code

```
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test-db", props);
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(FILTER_7);
        prepStatement.setString(1,"{AAAAAAIAAAAAIAAAAAAAAgAAAAAgAAAAAAACAAAAACAAAAAAAAIAAgAAIAAgAAAAAgACAAAgACAAAAAAAAIA}");
        prepStatement.setString(2,"{gAAAAAAQAAAAAAIAAABAAAAAAAgAAAAAAQAAACAAAAAABAAAAIAAAAAAEAAAAAACAAAAQAAAAgAIAEAAAAAA}");
        prepStatement.setInt(3, 1979);
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long iter = 0;
        while (true) {
            ResultSet resultSet = prepStatement.executeQuery();
            long count = 0;
            while(resultSet.next()) {
                ++count;
            }
            System.out.println("Iteration: "+iter +" Entries: "+ count + " time :" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0));
            ++iter;
        }
```

Comment: do you have index on table?

Comment: Sounds like PreparedStatement caching could be the culprit. Try to disable the caching to get a new execution plan each time (`prepareThreshold=0` in the [JDBC URL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters))

Comment: Will closing `ResultSet` after the `++count;` loop help?